# Counter item inside two "xsl:for-each" cicle with xslt language

Tags: html, xml, xslt, count

I wish I could count the total rows of the two for-each would be possible?

The xml is:

```
<root xmlns="">
<General>
 <Data>
<Number>123456</Number>
<Date>2018-10-22</Data>
<LineRefer>0001</LineRefer>
<LineRefer>0002</LineRefer>
</Data>
<Data>
<Number>789456</Number>
<Date>2018-10-22</Data>
<LineRefer>0003</LineRefer>
<LineRefer>0004</LineRefer>
</Data>
</General>
<Services>
<Details>
<LineNumber>0001</LineNumber>
<Description>test description</Description>
</Details>
<Details>
<LineNumber>0002</LineNumber>
<Description>test description</Description>
</Details>
<Details>
<LineNumber>0003</LineNumber>
<Description>test description</Description>
</Details>
<Details>
<LineNumber>0004</LineNumber>
<Description>test description</Description>
</Details>
</root>
```

this is the xsl

```
       <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" />

  <xsl:key name="services" match="Services/Details" use="LineNumber" />

  <xsl:template match="root">
<html>
<head>
  <title>HTML Document Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="page">
    <xsl:for-each select="General/Data" >
      <h1><xsl:value-of select="Number" /></h1>
      <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('services', LineRefer)">
           <li><xsl:value-of select="LineNumber" /> | <xsl:value-of   select="Description" /> </li>
      <xsl:if test="(count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) mod 40 = 0 ">
       <!--here insert the pageBreak-->
      </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </ul>
    </xsl:for-each>
            </div>
           </body>
        </html>
     </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output is :
**number 123456**
0001 | test description
0002 | test description
**number 789456**
0003 | test description
0004 | test description

If I use that xsl code I know that the lines are 4, but I would like the count to return me 6
I would like to know the exact number of lines. At the moment I use an inaccurate system and I only count the lines of the second loop.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a sample of your input XML and your expected output please? It would also help to show how the xsl:key is defined. Thank you!

Comment: Why is the total row = 3 in each case? There are 2 numbers * 2 descriptions, so the result should be either 2 and 4, or 4 in both.

Comment: @michael.hor257k : Can it be okay? I tried to be as clear as possible, Sorry for the mistake

Comment: You still haven't showed us the key. And your input XML is not well-formed. And now we don't even know what your expected result is: do you want just the total number of lines, or an accumulating counter, or ..?

Comment: Unfortunately, the xml can not edit it .. I would like to count the number of lines and every 40 lines create a pageBreak .. I can not create a counter

Answer (score 0):

you could add a variable in your outer loop with the current position and use it in your calculation

```
<xsl:for-each select="General/Data" >
<xsl:variable name="outerPos" select="position()"/>

<xsl:for-each select="key('services', LineRefer)">
    <li><xsl:value-of select="LineNumber" /> | <xsl:value-of   select="Description" /> </li>
    <xsl:if test="(count(preceding-sibling::*) + $outerPos) mod 40 = 0 ">
```

Comment: : Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I have already tried but it creates problems when the elements are many

Comment: There are two problems with this approach: **1.** You don't know what the `key()` retrieves and from where - so you cannot be sure the retrieved nodes are siblings, let alone adjacent siblings. You should have used `position()` here too. -- **2.** You cannot just add the two counters. For example, if there are 2 "outer" nodes and 3 "inner" nodes, your combined counter will count: 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5. You need to multiply the outer counter ( - 1 ) by the number of the inner nodes , before adding it to the inner counter.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Sorry but I did not understand what you mean

Comment: @Alm It means you cannot use this. Please edit your question as requested by Tim C.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: At the moment I use the loop you see at the top of the question .. it is not accurate but it covers me quite well .. I would like to understand how to have a precise counter but what you wrote to me is difficult to understand

Comment: @Alm This is a waste of time. You have been asked to provide more details by both Tim C and by me. Please edit your question and provide the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Given a **well-formed** input such as:

**XML**

```
<root xmlns="">
  <General>
    <Data>
      <Number>123456</Number>
      <Date>2018-10-22</Date>
      <LineRefer>0001</LineRefer>
      <LineRefer>0002</LineRefer>
    </Data>
    <Data>
      <Number>789456</Number>
      <Date>2018-10-22</Date>
      <LineRefer>0003</LineRefer>
      <LineRefer>0004</LineRefer>
      <LineRefer>0005</LineRefer>
    </Data>
  </General>
  <Services>
    <Details>
      <LineNumber>0001</LineNumber>
      <Description>test description</Description>
    </Details>
    <Details>
      <LineNumber>0002</LineNumber>
      <Description>test description</Description>
    </Details>
    <Details>
      <LineNumber>0003</LineNumber>
      <Description>test description</Description>
    </Details>
    <Details>
      <LineNumber>0004</LineNumber>
      <Description>test description</Description>
    </Details>
    <Details>
      <LineNumber>0005</LineNumber>
      <Description>test description</Description>
    </Details>
  </Services>
</root>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <count-lines>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(General/Data) + count(General/Data/LineRefer)"/>
    </count-lines>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<count-lines>7</count-lines>
```

---

To assign a cumulative counter to each `LineRefer` (while including the parent `Data` in the count), you can do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="General/Data">
            <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
            <xsl:for-each select="LineRefer">
                <xsl:variable name="j">
                    <xsl:number count="LineRefer" level="any"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <line-num>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$i + $j"/>
                </line-num>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<output>
  <line-num>2</line-num>
  <line-num>3</line-num>
  <line-num>5</line-num>
  <line-num>6</line-num>
  <line-num>7</line-num>
</output>
```

Comment: does not work . Thanks for the help, I would need a counter that starts every page jump from scratch. The only solution to which I thought and to use two steps .. The first step change the xml and with the second I read with a single loop the nodes

Comment: @Alm I tested this so I can say with confidence that it does work. It may not do what you need, because you haven't clarified what you need - despite being asked numerous times to do so. And now I had enough of this.

Comment: Sorry if I can not get away well my English is elementary .. in this example you can see what I would like to do .. I would like to count the lines exactly http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzRw/4 ... every 3 insert pagebreak but the lines are 4

Comment: Good luck with that. I said I had enough of this, so it's no use to keep this on.

Comment: Excellent reaction .. you're the best